# How to identify location from a given input in a semantic way

Tags: machine-learning, agi, deep-neural-networks, data-preprocessing, artificial-consciousness

I have a sample use case, where user will give us a xls file with some location data. Where may be location information is given in different ways , sometime its IATA code, sometimes its standard abbreviation, sometimes they use own abbreviation or sometime just a short name of that location too and it can be in any format.

Now job of my application will take XLS as input and convert it my standard. By “My Standard” I mean to say I have a complete data set with almost all location in my database.

So, In simple words it will map user given input to my standard location name, which stored in my DB.

My model should have that capability also , where may be , if for any location it not able to map with any data in my location DB , I will train the model with that data. My "train" I mean to say I will map that user input with any location of master data.

Next time onward, if model receive same input, it should be able to map it with my master data, as per my last training.

Sample User Input and inference for location:

[image]

Can any one suggest any suitable solution this use case , Just a outline of though would be very helpful and will be appreciated.

I tried with fuzzywuzz to solve this problem, But that did not help me much to solve the use case completely.

Comment: If something is not in your database, how can you then know what the nearest known place is?

Comment: This sounds more like a database lookup operation or data cleaning to me than ML.

Comment: @emely_pi , Thanks for your reply ...  I presume no , May be I am not able to articulate the issue. In database search how will you map Pimpri to pune or HCM City to Ho Chi Minh City? every time it would be same , for other user it can be Ho C M City also , as I mentioned in the post "sometime its IATA code, sometimes its standard abbreviation, sometimes they use own abbreviation or sometime just a short name of that location too and it can be in any format"

Comment: @OliverMason , by DB I mean say my application master DB.

Comment: @sujoy If a place is not in your DB, you do not know where it is, and thus you don't know what the nearest place in your DB is. In your example it is _Pimpri_, but what about _Ghljhwkdjgj_? To a computer that is equally unknown.

Comment: @OliverMason , by database in this case I mean to , application limited scope database. Not the database used for location Search process. Obviously some where some how we have to map this near location of Pimpri is pune.